# datagridview not binding or not showing any error in vb.net windows application

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying fill datagridview but it is not showing also not showing any error. I have used application config file. Am just a beginner in vb.net

here my code ............

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration



Public Class Form1





   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim con As New  SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCS").ConnectionString)
    Try
        Dim cmd As String = "select * from tblemp"
        con.Open()

        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "tblemp")
        dgv.DataSource = ds


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

-----------------------app config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="DBCS"
     connectionString="Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="system.data.sqlclient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
     <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for    My.Application.Log -->
        <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="FileLog"/>
                <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="FileLog"
             type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" 
             initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
        <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
        <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
    </sharedListeners>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer.. need to mention datamember for datagridview

```
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "tblemp")
    con.close
    dgv.DataSource = ds
    dgv.DataMember = "tblemp"
```